# Cómo ordenar un array de objetos por uno de sus elementos [PHP]

Tags: php, array

En el momento actual me encuentro con que no acierto a ordenar un array de objetos usando como índice a ordenar una de sus claves.

Pongamos que el array viene tal que así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => e6930148-319f-4b87-bb57-8aae98adfc55
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2018-05-03T08:57:30+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T08:59:17+02:00
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 4263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )
```

Y yo lo que necesito es que se ordenen todos los resultados por el valr de StartDate y descendente, para tener siempre el más reciente como primer registro.

He intentado generando una función de comparación

```
  function comp($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

Generando un nuevo array con los datos que obtengo

```
  foreach ($json as $datos) {
    $id = $datos->Id;
    $estado = $datos->State;
    $fechaIni = $datos->StartDate;
    $fechaFin = $datos->EndDate;
    $proceso = $datos->Configuration->ProcessId;

    array_push($arrayDatos, $datos)
  }
```

Y llamándola luego desde un uksort

```
  uksort($arrayDAtos, comp(xxxx,yyyy))
```

Pero es aquí donde creo que me he liado, porque no sé de qué manera pasarle a la función **comp** los valores necesarios para que ordene por StartDate.

Vamos, que no tengo nada claro ni el funcionamiento de uksort ni qué debe hacer exactamente la función **comp**

Comment: uksort sirve para ordenar arrays por los indices, asi que no creo que te sirva

Comment: Ajam, entonces de qué manera puedo hacer la ordenación que necesito? Seguro que debe poderse hacer de alguna manera.

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido y ha resultado válido de momento, es usar una tabla en mysql auxiliar donde meter todos los datos y luego hacer un select, pero esto al final es tiempo de procesado, y quiero minimizarlo todo lo que pueda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar en efecto [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php), si no te importa que los índices (numéricos)  del nuevo array cambien, en caso contrario podrías usar [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.uasort.php). Ambas funciones admiten una función como parámetro donde indicamos cómo queremos el orden. En este caso usaremos nuestra función `object_sorter`.

Propongo esta función, algo avanzada y sin duda mejorable que ofrece las siguientes ventajas:

- Puedes re-usarla para **ordenar por cualquier clave** del objeto que sea pasada en parámetro
- Admite un **parámetro de orden** opcional (`DESC`), para cuando se quiera ordenar de forma `DESC`endente.
- Usa [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strnatcmp.php), aprovechando de sus ventajas, para hacer las comparaciones.

La función es simplemente esta:

```
function object_sorter($clave,$orden=null) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($clave,$orden) {
          $result=  ($orden=="DESC") ? strnatcmp($b->$clave, $a->$clave) :  strnatcmp($a->$clave, $b->$clave);
          return $result;
    };
}
```

Y para usarla, solamente le pasas el array.

- Para que lo ordene de forma `ASC`endente por la clave `StarDate`:

  ```
  usort($objDatos, object_sorter('StartDate'));
  ```
- Para que lo ordene de forma `DESC`endente por la clave `StarDate`:

  ```
  usort($objDatos, object_sorter('StartDate','DESC'));
  ```

---

**Prueba completa:**

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/BDPT82511)**</kbd>

```
<?php
/*PHP: Ordenar array de objetos por uno de sus miembreos con usort - https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/161586/29967*/ 
/*Función*/
function object_sorter($clave,$orden=null) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($clave,$orden) {
          $result=  ($orden=="DESC") ? strnatcmp($b->$clave, $a->$clave) :  strnatcmp($a->$clave, $b->$clave);
          return $result;
    };
}

/*Objeto original*/

    $objDatos = 
        array(
                0 => (object) array(
                                    'Id' => 'e6930148-319f-4b87-bb57-8aae98adfc55',
                                    'State' => 'FINISHED',
                                    'StartDate' => '2019-05-03T08:57:30+02:00',
                                    'EndDate' => '2018-05-03T08:59:17+02:00'      
                                   ),
                1 => (object) array(
                                    'Id' => '4263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5',
                                    'State' => 'FINISHED',
                                    'StartDate' => '2018-05-03T10:15:39+02:00',
                                    'EndDate' => '2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00'      
                                   ),
                3 => (object) array(
                                    'Id' => '5263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5',
                                    'State' => 'FINISHED',
                                    'StartDate' => '2020-05-03T10:15:39+02:00',
                                    'EndDate' => '2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00'      
                                   ),            
            );

/*Original*/
echo "OBJETO ORIGINAL:".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
print_r($objDatos);


/*Orden por defecto (ASCendente)*/
usort($objDatos, object_sorter('StartDate'));
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."ORDEN ASCENDENTE:".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
print_r($objDatos);


/*Orden DESCendente (indicándolo en parámetro)*/
usort($objDatos, object_sorter('StartDate','DESC'));
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."ORDEN DESCENDENTE:".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
print_r($objDatos);


?>
```

---

**Resultado:**

OBJETO ORIGINAL:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => e6930148-319f-4b87-bb57-8aae98adfc55
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2019-05-03T08:57:30+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T08:59:17+02:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 4263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 5263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2020-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )

)
```

ORDEN ASCENDENTE:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 4263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => e6930148-319f-4b87-bb57-8aae98adfc55
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2019-05-03T08:57:30+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T08:59:17+02:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 5263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2020-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )

)
```

ORDEN DESCENDENTE:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 5263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2020-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => e6930148-319f-4b87-bb57-8aae98adfc55
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2019-05-03T08:57:30+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T08:59:17+02:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 4263f6a9-6e49-4aee-bcf6-70e1d2578fc5
            [State] => FINISHED
            [StartDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:39+02:00
            [EndDate] => 2018-05-03T10:15:58+02:00
        )

)
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

> **NOTA:** Función que podemos adaptar, mejorar e incorporar a nuestra biblioteca utilitaria de código.

Comment: Si se necesita **insensible** a mayúsculas y minúsculas usad [strnatcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strnatcasecmp.php)

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer usando usort asi:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['startDate']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['startDate']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($arrayDatos, 'date_compare');
```